# Display recent data after button is clicked(different page)

Tags: php, mysql, lastinsertid

I have a modal that adds a project to database.

When I clicked the add button I want the recent project data to appear on a pop-up window after the modal has been closed.

I think it is all about the LAST_INSERT_ID() function but it does not work.

HELP!

Function of my add button:

```
<?php
if (!empty(isset($_POST["submit_n"]))) {

    $project_name   = $_POST["project_name"];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_ongoing_project(project_name) VALUES('$project_name')";
    $res = $con->query($sql);
    header("Location: view_result.php");
}
?>
```

I wanted the header to be like this :`view_result.php?id=$id` 
$id = last insert id ???

Comment: where is your code in question ^_^

Comment: @Deep: That's the code. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write like this,

```
 $res = $con->query($sql);
 header("Location: view_result.php?id=".$con->insert_id);
```

It should work, and as a suggestion please use mysqli.

Comment: It worked! I did not know it was that simple. Thank you so much!